# Implementing FadeTransition in JavaFX FXML application

Tags: java, javafx, transition, fxml

I have seen fade in implemented in JavaFX application, but how can I implement it in FXML application?

This is how oracle docs says it should be done:

```
FadeTransition ft = new FadeTransition(Duration.millis(3000), someNode);
ft.setFromValue(0.1);
ft.setToValue(1.0);
ft.play();
```

This is the main that loads the application:

```
public class MainApp extends Application {

private final double MINIMUM_WINDOW_WIDTH = 500.0;
private final double MINIMUM_WINDOW_HEIGHT = 400.0;
private final double MAXIMUM_WINDOW_WIDTH = 800.0;
private final double MAXIMUM_WINDOW_HEIGHT = 600.0;

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("MainApp.fxml"));

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    //Set window title
    stage.setTitle("My app");

    //Set minimum window size
    stage.setMinWidth(MINIMUM_WINDOW_WIDTH);
    stage.setMinHeight(MINIMUM_WINDOW_HEIGHT);

    //Set maximum window size
    stage.setMaxWidth(MAXIMUM_WINDOW_WIDTH);
    stage.setMaxHeight(MAXIMUM_WINDOW_HEIGHT);

    //Set window icon
    stage.getIcons().add(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/images/favicon-96x96.png")));
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();

}

  /**
   * @param args the command line arguments
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      launch(args);
  }

}
```

An example is very much appreciated!
Thank you!

EDIT:

This is what I am trying to do: Application opens fading in from opacity 0.1 to 1.

This what I've tried, but it doesn't work.

```
    public class MainApp extends Application {

    private final double MINIMUM_WINDOW_WIDTH = 500.0;
    private final double MINIMUM_WINDOW_HEIGHT = 400.0;
    private final double MAXIMUM_WINDOW_WIDTH = 800.0;
    private final double MAXIMUM_WINDOW_HEIGHT = 600.0;

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("MainApp.fxml"));

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    //Set window title
    stage.setTitle("My app");

    //Set minimum window size
    stage.setMinWidth(MINIMUM_WINDOW_WIDTH);
    stage.setMinHeight(MINIMUM_WINDOW_HEIGHT);

    //Set maximum window size
    stage.setMaxWidth(MAXIMUM_WINDOW_WIDTH);
    stage.setMaxHeight(MAXIMUM_WINDOW_HEIGHT);

    //Set window icon
    stage.getIcons().add(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/images/favicon-96x96.png")));

    //Fade in transition
    FadeTransition ft = new FadeTransition(Duration.millis(3000), root);
    ft.setFromValue(0.1); 
    ft.setToValue(1.0);
    ft.play();

    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();

}

  /**
   * @param args the command line arguments
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      launch(args);
  }

}
```

Comment: Just put the code in your controller class.

Comment: Ok, this would go to the initialize method.
But how can I make the whole stage fade?
new FadeTransition(Duration.millis(3000), someNode);

SomeNode has to be the stage, but the stage can't be Node :S

Comment: Can you edit your question and explain what you are trying to do? What are you trying to fade (and when)? Is the stage supposed to be transparent? Post some code to show what you have tried.

Comment: Edited my question with sample code

Comment: Apart from the fact that you made it fade out, not in, what does "doesn't work" mean? How does it differ from what you want it to do?

Comment: I meant that it doesn't fade in :)
Just tried the same fade transition code on other stages. Works fine.
Yep, the provided code was fading out, sorry my mistake!

Comment: It works fine when I try it. Can you create a complete, executable example? (Either replace the FXML with some content generated in code, or post a simple FXML that fails to fade in.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using TimeLine:

```
public class MainApp extends Application {

    private final double MINIMUM_WINDOW_WIDTH = 500.0;
    private final double MINIMUM_WINDOW_HEIGHT = 400.0;
    private final double MAXIMUM_WINDOW_WIDTH = 800.0;
    private final double MAXIMUM_WINDOW_HEIGHT = 600.0;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = new VBox();
        root.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #000;");
        //FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("MainApp.fxml"))

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        //Set window title
        stage.setTitle("My app");

        //Set minimum window size
        stage.setMinWidth(MINIMUM_WINDOW_WIDTH);
        stage.setMinHeight(MINIMUM_WINDOW_HEIGHT);

        //Set maximum window size
        stage.setMaxWidth(MAXIMUM_WINDOW_WIDTH);
        stage.setMaxHeight(MAXIMUM_WINDOW_HEIGHT);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

        //Fade in
        DoubleProperty opacity = root.opacityProperty();
        Timeline fadeIn = new Timeline(
                new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, new KeyValue(opacity, 0.0)),
                new KeyFrame(new Duration(4000), new KeyValue(opacity, 1.0))
        );
        fadeIn.play();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }
}
```